# SQL Alchemy Querying Across Star Schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to map an existing star schema database using SQL alchemy and am having trouble structuring my joins.  I've read through the docs and stack overflow but haven't found a clear answer.

Here is the simple layout of my classes.  School and Student are different dimension tables with the contextual information. StudentScore is a fact table that is a many to many association table, and has a row for every student-assessment.

```
class School(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DimSchool'

    id = Column('SchoolKey', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('SchoolName', String)
    district = Column('SchoolDistrict', String)

class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DimStudent'

    id = Column('StudentKey',Integer, primary_key=True)
    srcstudentid = ('SrcStudentId', Integer)
    firstname = Column('FirstName', String)
    middlename = Column('MiddleName', String)    
    lastname = Column('LastName', String)

class StudentScore(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'FactStudentScore'

    StudentKey = Column('StudentKey', Integer, ForeignKey('DimStudent.StudentKey'), primary_key = True)
    SchoolKey = Column('SchoolKey', Integer, ForeignKey('DimSchool.SchoolKey'), primary_key = True)
    PointsPossible = Column('PointsPossible', Integer)
    PointsReceived = Column('PointsReceived', Integer)

    student = relationship("Student", backref='studentscore')
    school = relationship("School", backref='studentscore')
```

I'm trying to query for a given school, joined on StudentScore and Student to return what would be one row for every student, with their score and school associations.  Ultimately I will be putting this into a pandas dataframe.  Can someone provide a clear example on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a many-to-many relationship, use the `secondary=...` argument to `relationship()` and point it to an association table. See
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many for a complete example.

In case the junction table contains additional data, fancier patterns with association objects and association proxies make client code relatively straight-forward. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html for an example similar to the case presented in the original question.

Comment: Is this still relevant if the intermediary table also contains information and attributes I want?  The scores the students got on the tests lives on in the association table here.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what association objects (and proxies) are for. Follow the link and read on to the next section. :)  I've updated my answer to also point to association proxies.

Comment: worked like a charm.  the association proxy is exactly what I needed.